# Cycles per second to cycles per microsecond

Tags: cycle

Lets say i have 70,000 cycles per second, and i want to get cycles per microsecond. so is it:
7,000,000 * 10^6   or is it 7,000,000 * 10^-6

(1 sec is 10^6 micro)
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing, you probably messed up the numbers but it will be 70,000 * 10^-6  which is also 0.07 Cycles per microseconds.